# don't match string in brackets php regex

Tags: php, regex, brackets

I've been trying to use preg_replace() in php to replace string. I want to match and replace all 's' in this string, but I just came with solution only mathching 's' between 'b' and 'c' or 's' between > <. Is there any way I can use negative look behind not just for the character '>' but for whole string ? I don't want to replace anything in brackets.

```
     <text size:3>s<text size:3>absc
     <text size:3>xxetxx<text size:3>sometehing
```

edit:
just get 's' in >s< and in bsc. Then when I will change string for example from 's' to 'te', to replace 'te' in xtex and sometehing. So I was looking for regular expression to avoid replacing anything in <....>

Comment: Can you make show the string you want to parce and successful result? And probably what you get instead. Your explanation at the moment is a bit off.

Comment: You mean to [skip `<`...`>` like this?](https://regex101.com/r/zD9iJ0/1)

Comment: @Yauheni Prakopchyk Sorry my question was little bit confusing. I will edit the question, but thanks to answer below I understand it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '/((<[^>]*>)*)([^s]*)s/';
$replace = '\1\3■';                                      # ■ = your replacement string

$result = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $str );
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eW6lS3/1)**</kbd>

Pattern explanation:

```
(               # group 1:
(<[^>]*>)*      # group 2: zero-or-more <...>
)    
([^s]*)         # group 3: zero-or-more not “s”
s               # litterally “s”
```

If you want match case-insensitive, add a “i” at the end of pattern:

```
$pattern = '/((<[^>]*>)*)([^s]*)s/i';
```

**Edit: Replacement explanation**

In the search pattern we have 3 groups surrounded by round brackets. In the replace string we can refer to groups by syntax `\1`, where `1` is the group number.

So, replace string in the example means: replace group 1 with itself, replace group 3 with itself, replace “s” with desired replacement. We don't need to use group 2 because it is included in group 1 (this due to regex impossibility to retrieve repeating groups).

In the demo string:

```
abs<text size:3>ssss<text size:3><img src="img"><text size:3>absc
└┘╵└───────────┘╵╵╵╵└───────────────────────────────────────┘└┘╵╵
└─┘└────────────┘╵╵╵└──────────────────────────────────────────┘
 1  2            345 6
```

Pattern matches:

```
     group 1    group 3       s
    ---------  ---------  ---------
1 >     0          1          1
2 >     1          0          1
3 >     0          0          1
4 >     0          0          1
5 >     0          0          1    
6 >     3          1          1
```

The last “c” is not matches, so is not replaced.

Comment: Nice solution, but I don't fully understand it. So both groups are written before the `s` in the pattern, but it also replaces an `s` if it appears after a <...> expression. How does that work?

Comment: @Andru answer edited. Let me know if it is a bit clearer.

Comment: Wow! Your additional explanation taught me a lot about substitution via regular expressions! Your illustration helped me to get the idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all` to get all the `s` letters and use it with flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to get the indices.

The regular expression `$pat` contains a negative lookahead and lookbehind so that the `s` inside the brackets expression is not matched.

In this example I replace `s` with the string `5`. Change to the string you want to substitute:

```
<?php

$s = " <text size:3>s<text size:3>absc";
$pat = "/(?<!\<text )s(?!ize:3\>)/";

preg_match_all($pat, $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $s[$match[1]] = "5";
}

print_r(htmlspecialchars($s));
```

Comment: OP: “I don't want to replace anything in brackets”

Comment: @fusion3k I see, I missed that.. let me try another regex

Comment: I suggest you to try with this string: `sabcs<text size:3>s<text size:3><text size:3>absc` ... ;)

Comment: Thank you and is there any way I can avoid whole string in brackets? For example when I want to replace 't' instead of 's' or anything else just to avoid replacing string in brackets?

Comment: Refer to the pattern in @fusion3k's answer. It does exactly what you want and is more general than my solution.